# Should the checkboxes for selection be aligned?

Tags: grid, data-tables, tree, data-tree

In case of hierarchical grid displaying nested data with selection checkboxes on the left column, should the checkboxes at parent and child level be aligned vertically in the case when the child rows is being right indented in comparison to the parent rows?

[image: nested selection grid]

As an example, should the checkboxes for the sub-rows in the image above be on the red cells or the green cells or somewhere else?

Comment: This is difficult to visualise. Could you show us some rough wireframes to illustrate what you're asking?

Comment: @AndrewMartin added an illustration

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is hierarchical, what happens when a parent row is selected? Does this mean the child rows are selected also or is it just the parent row.

If the selection of a parent row does influence the child rows, I would recommend to indent the child rows. Otherwise it would be difficult to understand why the checking of the parent row influences other checkboxes.

visually the indent of the checkboxes would enhance the clue that it is not just a table but a tree.

Comment: Yes, the selection of parent row would select all the child rows too. Do we have any study on the usability such a control that you can point me to?

Comment: I do not know of a study of exactly this situation.